# Haskell: Different in function declarations

Tags: haskell

I am writing the haversine formula in haskell. 
In one version of my function, the definition and declarations are as follows:

```
haversine :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
haversine lat1 lon1 lat2 lon2 = let dlon = (toRad lon2) - (toRad lon1)
                                    dlat = (toRad lat2) - (toRad lat1)
                                    a = sin(dlat/2)^2 + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin(dlon/2)^2
                                    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
                                in c*r
```

This function compiles fine. When I change the declaration to:

```
haversine :: (Double a) => a -> a -> a -> a -> a
```

I get the following error:

```
• Expecting one fewer argument to ‘Double’
  Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Double’ has kind ‘*’
• In the type signature:
    haversine :: (Double a) -> a -> a -> a -> a -> a
```

To my knowledge, by writing (Double a), I am subjecting the rest of the parameters labeled 'a' to the Double type class constraint. Why does the latter declaration result in this error?

Comment: You changed the first type declaration from `Double ->` to `Double =>` when you changed the second from `(Double a) ->` to `(Double a) =>`. This can't possibly be correct so I have taken the liberty of editing it back to `Double ->`.

Comment: `Double` is "constant" type constructor. It takes no argument. You can check it with `:k Double` in `ghci`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `Double a` isn't a valid constraint. You're looking for `Floating a`

2) Constraints are given on the left hand side of a `=>`, unlike function arguments which are on the left hand side of a `->`.

So to compile, your code should be

```
haversine :: Floating a => a -> a -> a -> a -> a
haversine lat1 lon1 lat2 lon2 = let dlon = (toRad lon2) - (toRad lon1)
                                    dlat = (toRad lat2) - (toRad lat1)
                                    a = sin(dlat/2)^2 + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin(dlon/2)^2
                                    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
                                in c*r
```

Assuming you have globally defined

```
r :: Floating a => a
toRad :: Floating a => a -> a
```

Comment: Why isn't Double a valid constraint? Isn't Double an instance of Floating?

Comment: Constraints constrain a *type* to a *class*. `Double` isn't a class.

Comment: Like MathematicalOrchid says, `Double` is a type, not a constraint.  In Haskell, just as types live in a different world than values, constraints live in a different world than types. To be technical, they have a different *kind*.  A simple data type like `Double` has kind `*`. Types of kind `*` are the only types that have values. `Maybe` has kind `* -> *`. It maps a type of kind `*` (like `Double`) to a new type of kind `*` (like `Maybe Double`).  `Floating` is a typeclass and has kind `* -> Constraint`. It maps a type of kind `*` to a constraint.

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, a *type* and a *class* are two different things.

There is a *type* named `Double`.

There is no *class* named `Double`.

Also, a class constraint must be followed by `=>`, not `->`.

You can constrain a variable by a *class* such as `Eq`, `Show`, etc. If you want it to be a specific *type*... well, just write that type instead of a variable.

Comment: I guess Skalla could write `haversine :: (a ~ Double) => a -> a -> a -> a -> a` to constrain `a` to be `Double`, but that'd be highly non-idiomatic.